# cursor.close() UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python Flask CRUD operation code. The GET, PUT, and DELETE methods are working fine, but the ADD method is not working. I am getting the error message "cursor.close()UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment". I have tried to rectify the issue but have been unable to do so.

This is my code

```
import pymysql
from app import app
from db_config import mysql
from flask import jsonify, flash, request
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from waitress import serve

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    try:
        _json = request.json
        _name = _json['name']
        _email = _json['email']
        _password = _json['pwd']
        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password and request.method == 'POST':
            #do not save password as a plain text
            _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
            # save edits
            sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(user_name, user_email, user_password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)"
            data = (_name, _email, _hashed_password,)
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql, data)
            conn.commit()
            resp = jsonify('User added successfully!')
            resp.status_code = 200
            return resp
        else:
            return not_found()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()

@app.route('/get')
def users():
    try:
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_user")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        resp = jsonify(rows)
        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp
        print(resp)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()

@app.route('/get/<int:id>')
def user(id):
    try:
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id=%s", id)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        resp = jsonify(row)
        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()

@app.route('/update', methods=['PUT'])
def update_user():
    try:
        _json = request.json
        _id = _json['user_id']
        _name = _json['user_name']
        _email = _json['user_email']
        _password = _json['user_password']        
        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password and _id and request.method == 'PUT':
            #do not save password as a plain text
            _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
            # save edits
            sql = "UPDATE tbl_user SET user_name=%s, user_email=%s, user_password=%s WHERE user_id=%s"
            data = (_name, _email, _hashed_password, _id,)
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql, data)
            conn.commit()
            resp = jsonify('User updated successfully!')
            resp.status_code = 200
            return resp
        else:
            return not_found()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()

@app.route('/delete/<int:id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_user(id):
    try:
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id=%s", (id,))
        conn.commit()
        resp = jsonify('User deleted successfully!')
        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp
    except Exception
```

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post full traceback you get.

Comment: looking at the code, in two places you have `if` blocks that check e-mail and password and `cursor` is defined inside. If the condition is not True, `cursor` in the `finally` branch of the `tr/except/finally` will not be defined

Comment: Maybe one of the three values - _name, _email or _pwd is missing or has different names